# Prisma, is it able to use underscore name convetion?

Tags: prisma, planetscale

Prisma, is it able to use underscore name convetion?

I personally don`t like camel case because of readability..

But it seems to use underscore when composing things like constrained index or unique. And it seems to automatically change to camelCase when doing prisma migrate. Is it better to just do it in camelCase?

I've always done underscore naming, so it's inconvenient.

Comment: Of course, you can use underscore.

Comment: @HoàngHuyKhánh yah yah but are there any other issues besides having a problem with column names when migrating?

Comment: I've been using underscore naming convention on my production project more than 1 year without facing any issue.

Comment: Except types generated from prisma look kinda ugly because it combine camelCase with snake_case. Example: `Prisma.province_districtsFindManyArgs`